# JQuery Adding Loop across multiple pages

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, addition

I've created a 3 page PHP form that carries the answers to the next page inside hidden fields. Each page has 3 questions, and depending on your answer, you can be "qualified" or "unqualified". Ideally I would like to count how many "unqualified" answers were selected total for all 3 pages. Here is my current code to count how many "unqualified" answers were selected on one page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('select').on('change', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            ct = $('select option.unqualified:selected').length;
            $("input[class=uqNum]").val(ct);
        });
    });
</script>
```

The script counts how many options with the class "unqualified" were selected and puts that number in a hidden field with class "uqNum".

The problem is when I go to the next page of the form and select another "unqualified" option, the number is then replaced with the number selected on THAT page, and doesn't continue to add to the number from the previous page. I feel like there should be a loop of some kind? How do you continue to add to a value when you go to another page?

Comment: To know if this will work it would be necessary to see the code for the 3 pages

Comment: If I were to do this I would do one of two things, 1) Use session to persist your answers 2) Make the form one page and hide each "new page" using css/javascript and reveal each "new page" using a next button.

Comment: I can't put it all on one page, i'd LOVE to actually. But my client specifically requested to have 3 separate pages for the form. I can persist the answer for the first page in a session, but how do I add to it when I go to the next page?

Comment: @AmirSyafrudin I can't make the form one page. It has to be 3 pages unfortunately...

Comment: If you are using session variables, you should make the calculation on the server side using that session variables. Just like what Brett suggested in his answer. :)

Comment: I'm sure your client has their reasons, but does it need to reload like a page submission, or can it not simulate a faked spinner or the like to appear like it's doing something magical in the background? I am just curious more than anything why they require 3 separate pages.

Comment: They want to track conversion rates via Google Analytics on where the users drop off on the form and then make changes to the form if necesssary to get better conversion rates. So they can see the number of people who went to step 1, step 2 and step 3.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense I guess. Alternatively, you could also store the progression in a database using ajax (only so far as the user's ip and what step they made it to)...but at that point, for sake of ease you will probably want to use a session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using PHP I would change storing the values in hidden options and change it to use Session values. Then each page you can access the values from the previous page.

You need to call `session_start()` somewhere at the beginning of every php script. Then you can access the values easily `$_SESSION['key_name'] = $value;`

Comment: I guess I can just have session values for each page, then add it up?

Comment: Yeah, when each page submits it's form you can save all the values to the session. Then on the final page do any calculations on the values from every page.